# Remotely open link on same page by clicking another link in jQuery

Tags: jquery

Weird question, but I have two links. I want to set it up so when I click link a, it will actually trigger the events in link b.

```
<a class="a" href="#">
<a class="b" href="http://www.google.com">
```

So, in the example above, when I click link a, google.com would open in the current browser.

The catch is that I need the link to read the entire a href, because I have specific actions linked to the class name of the link (lightbox).

I need this because when I pass the link through a `.html()` , although the link works fine, for some reason the class does not take, and I have not been able to find a workaround or solution thus far. Therefore I am trying to set it up so that when I click the link that passes through the `.html()` , it will actually click a hidden link posted elsewhere on the page.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('a.a').click(function() {
    $('a.b').click();
});
```

When `a.a` is clicked it will trigger `a.b`. Also your question is still vague after reading it 4 times

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    $('a.a').click(function() {
        window.location = $('a.b').attr('href');
    });
})
```

Or something like this

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function ()
    {
        $('a.a').click(function() {
            $('a.b').trigger('click');
        });

        $('a.b').click(function(){ alert("hello")});
    })
</script>
<a class="a" href="#">a</a>
<a class="b" href="http://www.google.com">b</a>
```